# @import '~@material/theme'; in styles.css doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, angular-material-theming

I got the error when I follow the instruction online
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
>   Module build failed:
>   @import '~@material/theme';
>   ^
>         File to import not found or unreadable: ~@material/theme.
>         in D:\Practice\angular\styles.scss (line 1, column 1)

I have no idea why it didn't find the material/theme or why it can't be imported as I can see @material/theme under my node_modules file.

```css
@import '~@material/theme';

// always include only once per project
@include mat-core();

// import our custom themes
@import 'my-theme.scss';
@import 'my-light-theme.scss';
@import 'my-dark-theme.scss';

.my-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($my-theme);
}

// additional css classes
// you can hardcode one of them on the <body> tag 
// or switch dynamically during runtime with [class]
.my-light-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($my-light-theme);
}

.my-dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($my-dark-theme);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The import path is not correct, it should be:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
```

You can see [here more information](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

Comment: I tried this already, it still not work, has the same error....I think it must something else goes to wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try file name without extension

```
@import '@angular/material/_theming.scss';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing the `_theming.scss` file this way (change the path to match yours):

> `@import "../../../node_modules/@angular/material/_theming";`

I tried `@import '~@angular/material/theming';` also using NPM *node-sass* and got the error this way...